# How to specify which column to read from a .csv file?

Tags: csv

More specifically, I have a .csv file that has a different row for each date. Each column represents a parameter for that data, i.e. high, low, precipitation, wind, etc...

Date, High, Low, Precipitation, Wind

1,35,12,0.2,12

2,38,15,0,7

3,32,20,0.4,8

I am trying to write a function that will read whichever column I pass to it. So for example, if I want to read the data for the precipitation, I will pass "Precipitation" to the function with the output being a vector with all of the precipitation data. However, if I want to read the High data, then I will pass that to my function instead. I've seen examples where you code in a specific number to read, but I'm trying to set it up where that is not known a priori. Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: In which programming language do you plan to do that?